# Let $A \in M_{n×n}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $(A − 2I)(A − 3I)(A − 4I) = 0$. Suppose $λ$ is an eigenvalue of $A$. Then $λ = 2$ or $λ = 3$ or $λ = 4$.

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A \in M_{n×n}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $(A − 2I)(A − 3I)(A − 4I) = 0$. Suppose $λ$ is an
eigenvalue of $A$. Then $λ = 2$ or $λ = 3$ or $λ = 4$.

I understand that I should use the lemma that for $p(x) \in \mathbb{R[x]}~~~$ $P(A)v=P(\lambda)v$, but I don't know what to do.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Whats is $(A − 2I)(A − 3I)(A − 4I)x$ if $Ax=\lambda x$?

Comment: $ (A−2I)(A−3I)(A−4I)x=0x=0$

Comment: Not correct. Think slowly.

Comment: $(\lambda-2)(\lambda-3)(\lambda-4)x$ ?

Comment: Right. Now finish the proof.

Comment: $0x=(A−2I)(A−3I)(A−4I)x=(λ−2)(λ−3)(λ−4)x$, $x$ is an eigenvector so $x \ne 0$, so we have $(λ−2)(λ−3)(λ−4)x=0$ iff  $λ=2$ or $λ=3$ or $λ=4$.

Comment: So, when I have $Ax=\lambda x$, I can always switch $A-cI$ with $\lambda -c$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As people commented, you just take $x\neq 0$ some eigenvector of $A$, such that $Ax= \lambda x$, and multiply it by the matrix $(A-2I)(A-3I)(A-4I)$. However, this is the zero matrix and hence
$$
0= (A-2I)(A-3I)(A-4I)x= (A-2I)(A-3I)(Ax-4Ix)= (A-2I)(A-3I)(\lambda x- 4x)= (\lambda-4)(A-2I)(A-3I)x= (\lambda-4)(\lambda-3)(A-2I)x= (\lambda-4)(\lambda-3)(\lambda-2)x,
$$
which implies that $\lambda$ must be equal to either $2,3$ or $4$.

Comment: There is something missing here, probably an $x$ at the very last equality. You started with a matrix, you cannot end up with a scalar.

Comment: @Medo You are right, I edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of $A$. Then $A$ is similar to a matrix $B$ such that $B$ is in the form of \begin{bmatrix}
\lambda & 0\\
0 & C
\end{bmatrix}.

Note that $C$ is $n-1 \times n - 1$ matrix where $B$ is $n \times n$ matrix. All similar matrices satisfy same polynomial. So $(B − 2I)(B − 3I)(B − 4I) = 0$. Thus $\lambda$ must be one of these values, 2,3 and 4.

Comment: Thanks! Where can I find a proof for this statement?

Comment: @CalculusLover Brown, William $\textit{A second Course in Linear Algebra}$. Or you can try yourself by using the fact $A=SBS^{-1}$ for some invertible matrix $S$.

Comment: Thank you for that!